# Drawing image in Canvas at an angle WITHOUT rotating the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am drawing an image in HTML 5 using canvas in JavaScript. I need to draw it at a rotated angle. I know this can be done by applying rotate(angle) function using the context of the canvas. But I need to do this **without rotating the canvas itself**.

Kindly suggest possible approach for this if it's possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can actually draw whatever you want to rotate into an offscreen canvas and draw that into your main canvas. I borrowed this code from a Google IO Talk:

```
rotateAndCache = function(image,angle) {
  var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var offscreenCtx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

  var size = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
  offscreenCanvas.width = size;
  offscreenCanvas.height = size;

  offscreenCtx.translate(size/2, size/2);
  offscreenCtx.rotate(angle + Math.PI/2);
  offscreenCtx.drawImage(image, -(image.width/2), -(image.height/2));

  return offscreenCanvas;
}
```

then cache it with:

```
rotobj = rotateAndCache(myimg,myangle)
```

and in your drawcode:

```
mycontext.drawImage(rotobj,x_coord,y_coord)
```

This is only useful if you have an object that is rotated by an angle only once and is subsequently only subject to transformations.

Comment: Thanks PeterT. That almost fits the bill what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Any chance you have the link to that talk?

Comment: @Alexander actually I do: http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/super-browser-2-turbo-hd-remix-introduction-to-html5-game-development.html   the Video is at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEocRtn_j9s

Comment: Is there a similar way to scale the image?

Comment: Isn't where a conversion error in `rotate(angle + Math.PI/2)`? Should be `rotate(angle * Math.PI/2)`.

Comment: @AinTohvri nope, the '+' was correct, it's just there to adjust the angle of 0 pointing right instead of up. Which is useful generally and in this case done because it allows for easier alignment toward the mouse cursor (taking the direct result of atan2).

Comment: @PeterT, thanks!  Some additions in my answer below (couldn't see how to add code to a comment).

Comment: Yes it works much better as `angle * Math.PI / 2`. With `+` the angles are all very odd.

Comment: @Hasen what is the logic for multiplying? You can just remove the `Math.PI/2` if you don't need the 90° offset. Angles need to be in radians, if you want to rotate in degrees then use the proper formula for that

Comment: @PeterT You mean your value for `angle` was not in degrees? Your answer seems stranger and stranger as time goes on. But anyway it works fine without the `+` like Ain Tohvri pointed out and the angle is in degrees which is what people are most comfortable with using.

Comment: @Hasen I didn't write the code, I just explained it. The reason why it's in radians is well explained by the context it's from

Comment: @PeterT In the real world we need angles in degrees so it works better without the `+`. That's the point we were trying to make.

Comment: @Hasen and I have been making the point that this example is from "the real world" in this case it was to rotate objects to point to another object like the mouse cursor. Tell me how you would calculate the rotation to some other object without doing 1. some trigonometry like `atan2` that returns radians 2. manually convert to degrees 3. pass the degrees to this function 4. convert the degrees back to radians because `canvasContext.rotate` takes radians as input. I understand that your use-case is different, that doesn't mean that your case is the only or most common one.

Answer (score 3):

When you apply transformation on canvas you don't rotate canvas. you just tell that all you.are going to draw will be transformed in particular way. If you want to avoid transformation to affect other commands use `save()` and `restore()` methods. They allow to save and restore settings of the canvas.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(30);
ctx.drawImage();
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to scale the image?

Comment: Yes, `scale` instead of `rotate`. And two parameters, horizontal and vertical scaling factors.

Answer (score 1):

I've upvoted @PeterT-- great snippet and works well-- thanks for that!  I did have to make 3 small changes to get this to work for me:


1. the max of width and height isn't enough: if you think about rotating a square, you need a circle whose diameter is the diagonal of the square (`var diam`).

2. the canvas needs to be translated back (or use save/restore).

3. the object x and y coordinates have to be adjusted for the canvas size.

So I ended up with:

```
    rotateAndCache = function(image,angle) {
        var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var offscreenCtx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');

        var size = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
        var diam = 2*((size/2)*Math.sqrt(2));                 // needs to be saved
        offscreenCanvas.width = diam;
        offscreenCanvas.height = diam;

        offscreenCtx.translate(diam/2, diam/2);
        offscreenCtx.rotate(angle);
        offscreenCtx.drawImage(image, -(image.width/2), -(image.height/2));
        offscreenCtx.translate(-diam/2, -diam/2);

        return offscreenCanvas;
}
```

And the adjusted draw position (needs to be saved in `rotateAndCache`):

`mycontext.drawImage(rotobj,x-(diam-width)/2,y-(diam-height)/2);`

Comment: if you want to be precise you need a circle with a diameter that is equivalent to the diagonal of the rectangle, so it'd be `var diam = Math.sqrt(image.width*image.width + image.height * image.height);` but yeah, I get your point.

Comment: Yeah, largest dimension is confusing, I meant diagonal.  The code should do that (it's a 1-1-radical 2 right triangle)

Comment: But that's the diagonal of a square with a length of `max(image.width, image.height)` on all sides is it not ? Which may or may not be slightly larger than the one of a rectangle with unequal side-lengths (at least it's not smaller, so it won't cause errors).

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible and you probably don't need it. Try this:

```
context.save() // Save current state (includes transformations)
context.rotate()
... draw image ...
context.restore() // Restore state
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to scale the image?