# Why can't I change CSS attributes of my image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a new image but I'm trying to resize it and add some transformations to it. How ever, they are not taking effect.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/chung9ey/3/

```
img.onload = function(){
    img.style.width = "500";
    img.style.height = "300";
    img.style.transform = "perspective(500px) rotateZ(30deg)";
    context.drawImage(img, 0 ,0);   
}
```

Comment: you need a unit on numerical CSS length values other than `0`

Comment: It should be `context.drawImage(img, topLeftCornerHorizontalPosition, topLeftCornerVerticalPosition, imageWidth, imageHeight);`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: As for adding a rotated image to canvas, it might not be possible using `img.style.transform`. See [Rotate and save image for JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34080762/3345375).

Comment: Here's another way: [Drawing image in Canvas at an angle WITHOUT rotating the Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198771/drawing-image-in-canvas-at-an-angle-without-rotating-the-canvas)

Comment: Based on that last link, I've written an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38234177/3345375).

Answer (score 5):

Styles change properties, not attributes. In order to change the actual attributes you would need to use

```
img.height = 300;

//or by native API
img.setAttribute("height",300);
```

and so on for each attribute you wanted to change. Note that attributes are part of the html element and not necessarily part of the css definition (more on that here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint).

Comment: But changing the style properties will make the style changes take effect.

Comment: @Barmar - No, not always.

Comment: @Barmar: either would work. OP should probably just use his existing routine with correct CSS (fixing the tiny typo), but this answer works because of the default user-agent styling.

Comment: This is not working for me either. https://jsfiddle.net/chung9ey/29/ . For some reason, new Image(100, 100) doesn't make it 100 x 100?

Comment: @user6432770 - This merely answers the question of how you change the attributes of your image. Perhaps you should rephrase the question or create another which highlights the problem that "is not working" for you, as it is clear to see the attribute changing here.

Comment: @user6432770 - Ah, based on your expansion.. so using that will make it 100x100. But when you draw it on the canvas it is not longer constrained to those dimensions.

Comment: Sorry, but if it's changing, shouldn't it fit into the canvas when I draw it?

Comment: @user6432770 In this case `new Image` is sufficient without specifying `(100, 100)` at all. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38234177/3345375). Oh, and if you specify an image size, it affects how the image is scaled to display on a web page, but its actual (internal) resolution remains the same.

Comment: @jkdev the thing is I wanna add css properties like rotateX, rotateY, rotatez,and perspective and not just rotate it in 2D.

Comment: @user6432770 Not sure offhand, but I would start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+transform+canvas

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.

```
document.getElementById("imageID").style.height="300px";
document.getElementById("imageID").style.width="500px";
```

That should change the element's style width and height to what you want. 
In the HTML script, it'd be

```
<img src="source.jog" id="imageID"/>
```

Comment: @dandavis I don't, but it can be changed to what the ID of the image is.

Comment: @TravisJ My bad then.

Comment: You don't need the `id` if you have the handle of the image itself (here, `img`).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6198815/3345375), change your JS to:

```
var img = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById("hello");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

img.onload = function(){
  context.save(); // Saves current canvas state (includes transformations)
  context.rotate(30); // This rotates canvas context around its top left corner...
  context.translate(-275, 125); // ...so you need to make a correction.
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 300);   
  context.restore(); // Restore canvas state
};

img.src = "https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png";
```

This essentially rotates the canvas's contents after the image is drawn on it.

Part of the image is off-canvas as a result of this rotation, so you may also want to scale the canvas to fit the rotated image.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcyksjoz/

Answer (score 0):

i would change the image size in the canvas and then manipulating the canvas through id

```
var img = new Image(100, 100);
var canvas = document.getElementById("hello");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
img.onload = function(){
    img.style.transform = "perspective(200px) rotateZ(30deg)";
    context.drawImage(img, 0 ,0, width,height); 
}

img.src = "https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/CHRY_200_2015.png";

document.getElementById("hello").style.width="300px";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chung9ey/27/